# Bug in textarea that gets displayed after clicking comment and edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

When I click the `add comment` link, a textarea appears. Again, when I click `edit` on the earlier comment, one more box gets opened. Below is image with more description...

[image]

http://picturepush.com/public/7546061

I believe the add comment one should get closed again...

Let me know what to do if I need to close second box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a bug, but [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

In your image, the first textarea is an edit of an **existing comment**.
The second textarea is used to post a **new comment**. These are clearly different feautures.

I occasionally use this feature to repost an incorrect comment. I click on "Edit comment", and move the text to a new box. Before submitting, I delete the previous comment, and click on "Add comment".